# Arquivo do Excel/VBA mais do que duplica de tamanho sem motivo aparente ao ser salvo

Tags: microsoft-excel, arquivo, vba

Estou trabalhando com o **Excel** e usando de alguns recursos de programação do **VBA** via módulos (sem usar de formulários), e tem ocorrido um problema, o arquivo atualmente tem **8MB** e eu salvo continuamente com outro nome, no mínimo, indicando nova versão/release a cada mudança importante; ocorre que de um salvamento para outro o arquivo passa a ter outro tamanho, porém, totalmente desproporcional.

Este arquivo passou de **8MB** para mais de **40MB**, e mais tarde, quando retornei à versão anterior com **8MB** ele passou para **16MB** depois de dias de trabalho.

Não houve inclusão de dados (volume) ou inserção de imagens, no máximo foram alterações pontuais na programação, nas formatações condicionais ou com formatação de borda direto nas células. Lembro de pelo menos em um dos casos ter gerado uma macro para verificar como tratar as alterações de bordas das células via **VBA**, mas foi só isso.

Quando eu reparo que o arquivo aumentou desproporcionalmente de tamanho, meu procedimento é copiar a programação atual do módulo alterado do **VBA** (texto), para o mesmo módulo do arquivo anterior com o tamanho reduzido, sobrepondo. Além de funcionar como esperado, ao salvar o tamanho continua como o original (**8MB**).

A questão é que isso pode ocorrer sem que se perceba a alteração no tamanho do arquivo, e quando percebido, ser tarde para voltar atrás depois de inúmeras modificações; portanto, nestes casos deve ficar algum “lixo” salvo, o que seria altamente recomendável eliminar.

Alguém conhece este problema e pode me ajudar?

Comment: É por isso que não uso salvamento automático do Excel...... Vá entender! Mistério!

Comment: Mas, pelo que percebi, acontece na seguinte situação: 
1) Ocultei algumas linhas e colunas; 2)  depois, acabo arrastando algumas fórmulas nas linhas e colunas visíveis; 3) Salvo o arquivo e BUM, ele aumentou de tamanho.

Comment: Isso acontece porque ao arrastar a fórmula eu avancei muito na última linha visível, e, por conseguinte, o excel preencheu todas as linhas ocultas com a fórmula das linhas visíveis. A dica é, ao arrastar alguma fórmula até o fim de uma linha visível não ir até o fim dela (borda inferior), apenas até ela ser selecionada. Para reverter, basta reexibir as linhas ocultas e apagar as fórmulas desnecessárias..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma vez tive um problema parecido com o Excel. Eu tinha uma planilha simples, sem macros, sem formulários, sem imagens. A única coisa que ela tinha eram informações nas células e a formatação. O tamanho inicial dela era de 5MB, porém depois de alterar algumas informações (inclui 5 novas linhas e exclui mais de 200) o arquivo passou para mais de **25MB**.

Depois de muito quebrar a cabeça resolvi copiar as informações para uma nova planilha. Como esperado o tamanho diminuiu e ficou em pouco mais de **3MB**.

Como fiquei intrigado continuei pesquisando e tentando arrumar a planilha "original". Depois de algum tempo resolvi tirar a formatação das células sem uso e, para minha surpresa, só de retirar as bordas das células em branco o arquivo ficou em pouco mais de **3MB**, exatamente igual ao outro arquivo.

Esse pode ser o seu caso também. Tente verificar a formatação das células, pode ser que isso resolva o seu problema.

Em último caso eu sugiro que exporte os módulos e importe em um novo arquivo, pelo menos para verificar como o novo arquivo vai se comportar e qual o tamanho dele após salvo.

Comment: Humberto, muito obrigado, é isso mesmo, peguei um  arquivo de 57MB e limpei as bordas de uma única área, e o tamanho caiu para 7MB. Excelente! Detalhe, não havia nada, nem bordas nesta área.... vai entender

Comment: Que estranho isso, pode ser que tenha ficado algum "lixo" de formatações anteriores. Mas que bom que te ajudou.

Answer (score 1):

É difíciil saber exatamente o que está acontecendo com o seu arquivo. Já tive situações parecidas e são muitas as variáveis que tem que ser levadas em conta para tentar reduzir o tamanho do arquivo. Vou tentar sugerir as causas mais comuns para tamanhos exagerados de documentos e algumas dicas de como reduzir.

1. **Formatação:** um problema bem frequente que ocorre, é quando aplicamos formatação em muitas células (formato de texto, preenchimento, bordas, alinhamento...), mas especialmente em colunas (ou linhas) inteiras e células vazias. Geralmente isso se resolve da seguinte maneira: vá até a última célula usada da sua planilha (`Ctrl`+`End` pode ajudar) e exclua todas as colunas a direita (até a coluna XFD) e todas as linhas a baixo (até a linha 1048576). Use formatação apenas nas célulcas efetivamente utilizadas. Repita a ação para todas as planilhas da sua pasta de trabalho.
2. **Grande quantidade de dados:** problema comum, mas difícil de ser contornado. Se vc trabalha com grande bases de dados em Excel, ou seja dezenas de colunas e dezenas de milhares de linhas, vc inevitavelmente vai se deparar com arquivos bem grandes. Tente enxugar a formatação dessas tabelas e bases de dados ao máximo e, se possível, fragmentar uma grande tabela em pequenas tabelas que podem ser correlacionadas com PROCV ou outras fórmulas a medida que precisar.
3. **Macro gerando sobrecarga:** Levando em conta o ponto 1 e 2, verifique se a sua Macro não está gerando sobrecarga de formatação e dados. Se ela mexe de alguma forma com formatações, verifique se ela não está aplicando formatações em células inúteis. Ou, se de alguma forma sua macro não está executando tabelas com milhares e milhares de linhas.
4. **Formato XLSB:** uma última dica que eu dou é, quando se trabalha com arquivos na casa dos MB e sua rotina permite tal adaptação, que vc salve sua planilha com o formato XLSB em vez de XLS, XLSX ou XLSM. Em grandes arquivos, esse formato pode ficar até 80% menor que os formatos tradicionais de arquivo Excel.

Espero que de alguma forma ajude. D~e uma boa revirada na internet que vc vai achar mais formas de salvar espaço.

Comment: Tash, obrigado pela resposta, vou analisar o que indicou... grato!

Comment: Tash, verifiquei o caso da extensão XLSB, o meu volume de dados é pequeno, a planilha é que é complexa, extensa, com várias abas interligadas e com várias formatações. No momento vou seguir as outras sugestões e provavelmente reduzirei ainda mais o tamanho, mas não descarto trabalhar com XLSB se precisar. Grato!.